# Delegate property of UITableView seems independent of the same property of its parent class "UIScrollView"

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Here is the description of the delegate property of UIScrollView in apple's document

```
UIScrollView: UIView, NSCoding {
  ...
  weak public var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?
  ...
}
```

And the delegate property of UITableView:

```
UITableView: UIScrollView, NSCoding {
  ...
  weak public var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
  ...
}
```

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. But the delegate property seems to be independent from that of UIScrollView.There is no `override` keyword in front of it. And they belong to different types, although UITableViewDelegate inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate. I think it is against the inheriting rule of swift. And i found it did after doing some test in my own class. Here is my test code:

```
public class SomeClassA {
    weak public var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?
}

public class SomeClassB: SomeClassA {
  //reporting "property 'delegate' with type 'UITableViewDelegate?' cannot 
  //override a property with type 'UIScrollViewDelegate?'"error
  weak public var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
}
```

where does the problem lie?

Comment: [this has more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724709/overriding-delegate-property-of-uiscrollview-in-swift-like-uicollectionview-doe?rq=1) -> Basically it says that it is the result of the underlying code being obj-c where overriding the delegate is possible. (no expert on obj-c at all)

Comment: @R Menke yeah, i think you are right. thanks

Comment: No problem, was very confused by it as well. Was considering a bounty on this question, but a couple of google searches later I found a possible answer.